# MacBook Pro 2011 battery not detected

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management

My MacBook Pro 2011 battery is not detected. There is no spill of water or whatsoever on my logic board. One day I took out the battery and when I placed it back the problem occurred.

So I tried replacing it with a new battery but the battery is still not detected and there's no battery logo when I power up my laptop.

Tried looking on Google and most advice was doing a SMC reset.

When I tried to do an SMC reset, it's not responding. Basically I cant even do a SMC reset on my laptop.

What else can I try?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you to clarify the following *"When I tried to do an SMC reset, it's not responding"*? That is, how did you try resetting the SMC? And, what does "it's not responding" mean? What actually happens?